# How to use MutationObserver with AlpineJS and detect when an element is added to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I need an external script to add an element the DOM. My Alpine method should react to that change. So inside one of my Alpine methods I added:

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(() =>{
    const myIframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
    if (document.contains(myIframe)) {
        this.myIframeIsAvailable = true;
        observer.disconnect();
    }
});
observer.observe(document, { attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: false, subtree: true });
```

Unfortunately, the observer constructor creates a new scope, so I can't access Alpine's `this` in there. How can I access `this` in there?

Initially I thought I could add something like `on:childrenHaveChanged` to my template, but I can't find a matching event for that.

Comment: Could you share the Alpine.js method? Since you have used the arrow syntax, the `this` should refer the first "non-arrow syntax" parent scope. When I put this observer snippet inside an Alpine.js `init()` method, it's working fine. Maybe something else in your method creates a new scope.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right ... I just created a pen to isolate the issue and it didn't occur. I'll check again.

Answer (score 0):

I must have made a mistake in my original syntax, because now the approach seems to work. Just in case anyone is looking for a solution:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kslstn/pen/qBVPJNQ?)

```js
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.data('myApp', () => ({
        elementHasBeenAdded: false,
        
        onClick(){
            const observer = new MutationObserver(() =>{
                const child = document.getElementById('child');
                if (document.contains(child)) {
                    this.elementHasBeenAdded = true;
                    observer.disconnect();
                }
            });
            observer.observe(document, { attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: false, subtree: true });
            
            const parent = document.getElementById('parent');
            let child = document.createElement('div');
            child.id = "child";
            child.innerHTML = "I'm a child";
            parent.appendChild(child);
        },
    }))
});
```

```html
<div id="parent" x-data="{...myApp()}">
    <p x-ref="paragraph">The value of elementHasBeenAdded is: <code x-text="elementHasBeenAdded">Loading ...</code></p>
    <p>Click here:</p>
    <button x-on:click="onClick()">Start observer</button>
</div>
```